# Exception encountered when calling layer "attention_weight" (type Attention)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, tensorflow2.0, attention-model

I am new to using attention. My input shape is per sample is of shape (6,128). I can't get my head around what the solution might be.

```
def MLSTM_FCN(shape, num_classes):
x = Input(shape=(6, 128))
ip = x
x = Masking()(ip)
x = LSTM(units=8)(x)
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
y = Permute((2, 1))(ip)
y = Conv1D(32, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = squeeze_excite_block(y)
y = Conv1D(512, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = squeeze_excite_block(y)
y = Conv1D(512, 9, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(y)
x = concatenate([x,y])
x = keras.layers.Attention(name='attention_weight')(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(ip, out)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy','AUC','Recall'])
model.summary()

return model
```

The error code is given below. Please help me solve the problem. Just a bit of additional information. I am trying to add the attention layer to a feature map concatenating the features of a CNN model and an LSTM model.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ddc4e6d2fec2> in <module>()
----> 1 model = MLSTM_FCN((X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), train_label.shape[1])

2 frames
<ipython-input-19-ac6ce541a216> in MLSTM_FCN(shape, num_classes)
     19     y = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(y)
     20     x = concatenate([x,y])
---> 21     x = keras.layers.Attention(name='attention_weight')(x)
     22     out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
     23     model = Model(ip, out)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/dense_attention.py in _validate_call_args(self, inputs, mask)
    186     if not isinstance(inputs, list):
    187       raise ValueError(
--> 188           f'{class_name} layer must be called on a list of inputs, '
    189           'namely [query, value] or [query, value, key]. '
    190           f'Received: {inputs}.')

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "attention_weight" (type Attention).

Attention layer must be called on a list of inputs, namely [query, value] or [query, value, key]. Received: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 520), dtype=float32).

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 520), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None
  • return_attention_scores=False
```